# Minify Query from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, minify

From MySQL Workbench I can beautify the SQL Query using shortcut `Ctrl + B`. Is there's way to minify the Query from MySQL Workbench?

The goal is I want to reduce usage and optimize the speed response. After few times tial to run query below, it's give a better performance for minified query, it's gonna big different for big data table.

Minified (duration: 1st try: *0.076* sec, 2nd try: *0.082 sec*, 3rd try: *0.071 sec*)

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(value) FROM keluar_masuk WHERE income_cost = 'income' AND currency = 'MYR')  + ((SELECT SUM(value) FROM keluar_masuk WHERE income_cost = 'income' AND currency = 'USD') * (SELECT value FROM site_data WHERE what = 'usd_to_myr')) as income, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM keluar_masuk WHERE income_cost = 'cost' AND currency = 'MYR')  + ((SELECT SUM(value) FROM keluar_masuk WHERE income_cost = 'cost' AND currency = 'USD') * (SELECT value FROM site_data WHERE what = 'usd_to_myr')) as cost
```

Beautified (Duration: 1st try: *0.146 sec*, 2nd try: *0.113 sec*, 3rd try: *0.125* sec)

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            SUM(value)
        FROM
            keluar_masuk
        WHERE
            income_cost = 'income'
                AND currency = 'MYR') + ((SELECT 
            SUM(value)
        FROM
            keluar_masuk
        WHERE
            income_cost = 'income'
                AND currency = 'USD') * (SELECT 
            value
        FROM
            site_data
        WHERE
            what = 'usd_to_myr')) AS income,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(value)
        FROM
            keluar_masuk
        WHERE
            income_cost = 'cost'
                AND currency = 'MYR') + ((SELECT 
            SUM(value)
        FROM
            keluar_masuk
        WHERE
            income_cost = 'cost'
                AND currency = 'USD') * (SELECT 
            value
        FROM
            site_data
        WHERE
            what = 'usd_to_myr')) AS cost
```

Comment: Paste it into a text editor with regex and replace "\s+" with " "

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simply: no, MySQL Workbench has no feature like that. It's really not something people want often.